# How do you handle multiple files in a form submission using Apache2::Upload?

Tags: perl, web-applications, upload, apache2, file-upload

I'm writing a small web application using Perl, `HTML::Mason` and Apache.

I've been using Mason's usual <%args> method for receiving 'normal' form parameters, and [`Apache2::Upload`](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Upload) for receiving files.

However, I want to write a page that allows a user to upload multiple files, and I'd like to take advantage of HTML5's `multiple` attribute to input fields. This will look to the server as though there were multiple file inputs in the form with the same name.

The interface for `Apache2::Upload` doesn't seem to directly support this, allowing you instead to just get the data for a file with a particular parameter name. The [documentation](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Upload) alludes to using `APR::Request::Param::Table`, but I can't find any documentation for doing that.

Please note that I'm not interested in answers that involve adding extra file input fields with different names. This is trivial to handle on the server, and my question doesn't involve front-end scripting at all.

Comment: Could the OP please post relevant selections of the code base? This would help myself (and others) give a more thorough answer/explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the multiple attribute (in the form as you described) and then, after submission, call the Apache request object's [`upload` method](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Request#upload). That will give you a list of `Apache2::Upload` instances.

Good luck!

Comment: Does the OP also need to know how to retrieve the request object? If so, I may be able to help with that.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this. Thanks.